# Prove that even functions are subgroup of real functions.

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, normal-subgroups

There is a theorem in which we should prove that even functions $f(x) = f(-x)$ are subgroup of real functions.

Our professor suggested that $\forall f(x), g(x) \in S, f(x) + (-g(x)) \in H$ then with the knowledge of $f(x) + (-g(x)) = h(x)$ show that $h(x) = h(-x)$.

I have searched a lot but couldn't find any resources about this theorem and how to prove it.

I thought let's think about the musts of being a group. First of all, it should be closed under an associative operation like $*$ and it is.

Second there should exist an identity element like $e$ which in this case it's true and we have $e = f(0) = 0$. But what about the existence of inverse element and how to use the even function to define it?

Comment: Well, what's the inverse of $f(x)$ in the group of real functions?

Comment: It is defined as -f(x) which is negative of our function.

Comment: Ok...and if $f(x)$ is even, can you show that $-f(x)$ is also even?

Comment: I don't think so...

Comment: "*I don't think so...*" that you personally can't show that $f$ even implies $-f$ even?  Or that you don't believe that $f$ even actually implies $-f$ even?  Just look at the definitions... Suppose that $f$ is even.  Then we know that $f(x)=f(-x)$ for each $x$.  Now... consider $-f$.  Can we tell whether $(-f)(x)$ is equal or not to $(-f)(-x)$?  Remember that $(-f)(x) = -(f(x))$ and use what we know about $f$ being even...

Comment: Similarly, in showing that $h(x)=h(-x)$ you just swap $f(x)$'s with $f(-x)$'s in the expansion as well as doing the same for $g$'s and it should fall right out into your lap.  This is not meant to be a tricky question, just one that confirms that you understand definitions and how to structure proofs.

Comment: Thank you for your response. I got it. If _f_ is even, then _-f(x)_ is also even. Cause functions have nothing to do with the "-" behind them and so even functions. Then by this, I can show that _h(x) = h(-x)_ (via expanding it) then it is finished. Right?

Comment: [Here's a MathJax tutorial](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5020/104041) :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $H=\{f:\Bbb{R}\rightarrow\Bbb{R}\ |\ f \text{ is even}\}=\{f:\Bbb{R}\rightarrow\Bbb{R}\ | \ f(-x)=f(x) \text{ for all } x\in \Bbb{R}\}$. We want to show that $H$ is a subgroup of the group of all real functions (under addition).

One of the subgroup test is to show that $H$ is nonempty subset and $f-g\in H$ whenever $f,g\in H$.

We first show that the identity of the group is an element of $H$. The identity of the group is the zero function ${0}:\Bbb{R}\rightarrow\Bbb{R}$ defined by $0(x)=0$ for all $x\in\Bbb{R}$. Since $0(-x)=0$ for all $x\in \Bbb{R}$, we conclude that the zero function is in $H$.

Next, let $f,g\in H$. We want to show that $f-g\in H$. Let $x\in \Bbb{R}$. By the assumption, $f(-x)=f(x)$ and $g(-x)=g(x)$. Therefore,
$$(f-g)(-x)=f(-x)-g(-x)=f(x)-g(x)=(f-g)(x).$$
This shows that $f-g\in H$.

By the subgroup test, we conclude that $H$ is a subgroup of the group of all real functions.

Comment: Nitpick: there is more than one subgroup test.

Comment: @Shaun Revised. Thanks for your comment.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. It really helped :).